# A question related to random variable with distribution function

Tags: probability, statistics

Let X be a random variable having the distribution function
$$
 f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 0,  & \text{if $x<0$ } \\
\frac{x}{2}, & \text{if $0 \leq x<1$}\\
\frac{3}{5},& \text{if $1 \leq x<2$}\\
\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x}{8}& \text{if $2 \leq x<3$}\\
1& \text{if $x\geq3$}
\end{cases}
$$

Then $P(2 \leq X<4)=?$

This is a continuous distribution function ,so $P(2 \leq X<4)=\int_{2}^4f(x)dx$.

But I am unable to find $f(x)$ in the interval [2,4), please help.

Thanks.

Comment: $P(2 \leq X<4)=P(2<X \leq 4)+P(X=2)-P(X=4)=F(4)-F(2)+P(X=2)-P(X=4)$. Also, your CDF is *not* continuous.

Comment: Also, $f(x)$ *is* the CDF, not the pd/mf.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** Despite the lower case lettering, $f(x)$ is clearly a Cumulative Distribution Function with step discontinuities.   In particular, there is a step discontinuity at $x=2$, representing a point mass we have to consider.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(2\leq X < 4) & = 1 -\mathsf P(X<2) \\[2ex] & = 1-\lim_{x\nearrow 2} f(x) & \textsf{NB: limit from below} \end{align}$$